# Comparing chained exponents

Tags: algorithm, math, exponentiation

Given two lists of small integers, is it possible to determine which list produces a larger result, when each element is raised to the power of the remaining elements? For example, the list `1,2,3` would be less than the list `5,4`, since `1^2^3 < 5^4`.

The challenge occurs when the lists are sufficiently long, and actually calculating the results of the lists far exceed the maximum numbers that can be accurately represented by a computer

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101138/complexity-class-of-comparison-of-power-towers

Comment: That is the right direction, but doesn't really take me 100% there. None of the algorithms provided work in all cases.

Comment: What is the size of the list?

Comment: up to 10000 ints, which are between 1-1000000